# Why float property does not work if width of elements is set?

Tags: html, css

Here is HTML Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>


<head>
    <title>Float</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Font Sizes.css">
</head>



<body>

    <div class="First">
        <img src="firstImage.png" alt="First Image of Article" class="FirstImage">
        <p> Picture No.1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Second">
        <img src="secondImage.png" alt="Second Image of Article" class="SecondImage">
        <p>Picture No.2</p>

    </div>

</body>
```

Here is CSS

```css
.First{
  width:430px;
  
  background-color: Red;
  float: left;
  
}
.Second{
   width:330px;
  
  background-color: Blue;
   
 
}
```

I tried different tricks but failed. Please Explain it in detail. I searched a lot but could not found my answer.The second element not arrange it self to the right side of first element. When i remove the width property from second element then it arranged at right.
With Width property:
[image]

Without Width Property on second element:
[image]

Comment: Your float property does work. What do you want to do? Put it all on the same line?

Comment: You haven't supplied enough info. Make sure the container allows enough room for the elements to sit side by side.

Answer (score 1):

div's are block level elements and you have only supplied a float on `First`. Putting a float on `Second` will give you the effect you desire IF the browser is wider than 760px;

Comment: Alternatively, set `margin-left: 430px;` on `.Second`